# Matplotlib's bar chart displays uneven bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

If we look at this code and x,y data,

```
rects1 = plt.bar([0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,1],[1, 2, 4, 10, 5, 9, 1,4, 9, 9],edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('Sample Mean')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
```

this displays the following graph
[image]

I can not understand how the x values go beyond 1 and even takes negative values. Also, why do the bars have different widths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your x-values are separated by a spacing of 0.1 and the default bar width is 1 so you see overlapping bars. The solution is to define the bar width. In your case, a bar width smaller than 0.1 will work perfectly fine. For instance, you can use `width=0.05` and you will get the following graph.

**Why negative?**: The bars are by default centered at 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on. So your first bar in the question was drawn centered at 0 and had a width of 1. That's why it was spanning from -0.5 to +0.5.

```
rects1 = plt.bar([0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,1],
                 [1, 2, 4, 10, 5, 9, 1,4, 9, 9], width=0.05, edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('Sample Mean')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
```

[image]

**If you don't want bars at x<0**: You can align your bars to the right by passing argument `align='edge`.

```
rects1 = plt.bar([0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,1],
                 [1, 2, 4, 10, 5, 9, 1,4, 9, 9], width=0.05, align='edge', 
                 edgecolor='black')
```

[image]